# How to run Xampp with Skype and Lync

Tags: apache, networking

On a normal work day I start up Skype and Lync. Then I end up later in the day start up Xampp when I start developing.  The issue I run into is that if I start Skype and Lync up first then try to run the Apache server on Xampp it won't connect.  I've tried to get the Apache server to listen to 80, 8080, 8888, and other ports while the other 2 services are running and it can't launch until I fist shut down the other two services.  Now I can launch Apache then the other two and that works fine.

Is there a port or something that I can set Apache to that Skype and Lync won't interfere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that Lync was not interfering with Xampp.  Skype has a setting in it ( Tools>Options>Advanced>Connections).  Here you can define the port that Skype uses, as well as there is an option for Skype to use ports 80 and 443 as an alternative to incoming connections.  As a default this is selected.  Just unselect this option and click Save.

Thats what worked for me.  Also for windows users if you have installed IIS that will by default listen to port 80.  I found it easier to change the IIS port over the Apache port.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149605 - Note that this only goes up to IIS 7.0 but I used the same method on 8.x